# Obtaining a particular effect called "Lazy Mouse Smoothing" in a graphics application

Tags: mouse, switching

I'm using Pixelmator and Autodesk Sketchbook for drawing and I'd really love to have "lazy mouse smoothing".  This is a feature found in an application called [LazyNezumi](http://people.happycoders.org/kamih/lazynezumi), for Windows, that adds lag smoothing to the mouse.

Does anyone know of a solution for OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look around and can't find any specific sites that show how to enable/use 'lazy mouse smoothing' on OSX.

EDIT: Unless this does the job (SmoothCursor): http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41736/smooth-cursor/ - *have not used and am not affiliated with the app/company*

> SmoothCursor is a little utility that allows you to customize the acceleration settings of your mouse or trackpad separately. Totally recommended for drawing applications and FPS games*!

Developer's site: http://apps.leftbee.net/SmoothCursor

LazyNezumi itself states:

> I’m sorry but there is no Mac support, and I don’t plan on ever providing any (this was already tricky enough to program for Windows, and I’ve never owned a Mac or programmed with them).

Answer (score -1):

There's a new tool for Mac that is very similar:

http://www.hejbrush.com/apps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -